# I am trying to normalize a set of functional dependencies to 2NF and 3NF without loss of dependencies

Tags: database, database-normalization, 3nf

Following are the functional dependencies for table 'Portfolio' (containing information about the stocks bought by a particular user):

```
User_name, Stock_ID -> Quantity, Buying Price ;
Stock_ID -> Current_Price ;
Buying_Price, Current_Price -> Change ;
Quantity, Change -> Net_Change ;
```

Comment: this relation is not in 2NF as the non-prime attribute **current_price** is partially dependent on prime attribute stock_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you want such attributes in the table which seem to be redundant and only cause unnecessary functional dependencies? If 'change'='buying_price'-'current_price' and 'Net_change'='Quantity'*'change', then 'buying_price' and 'current_price' might be sufficient to achieve the same result with less redundancy, because 'Change' and 'Net_change' can be computed when required.

As Lordferrous already mentioned the relation is not in 2NF and to achieve that we would have to move partial dependency 'Stock_ID -> Current_Price' to a different relation. In the process FD3 (Buying_Price, Current_Price -> Change ) would be lost.

Comment: yes that's correct. Didn't have to have a table with such attributes. got the solution. thanks

Comment: @Neha Gupta, if you could accept the answer then it would be great :)